# persisting data in firefox plugin

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My plugin gathers some contextual data about every tab opened in firefox. I'd like it to be persisted and restored in case of browser crash. This data is not specific to a url of a tab but rather tab instance itself (it might be something like 'how many times there was a redirect performed in this tab'). I thought about attaching some data to firefox session (the one that gets restored when you open browser after crash) but I can't find any documentation whether this is at all possible or how to do it.

Is it possible to add data to firefox session? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is an API one might use to achieve this - [nsISessionStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsISessionStore).

you can store value like this:

```
var ss = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/sessionstore;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsISessionStore);
var currentTab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
var dataToAttach = "I want to attach this";
ss.setTabValue(currentTab, "key-name-here", dataToAttach);
```

and retrieve it like this:

```
var retrievedData = ss.getTabValue(currentTab, "key-name-here");
```

more info and examples can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Session_store_API).

Also, if like me, you want to use this in add-on SDK you can get appropriate service this way:

```
var { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');
var ss = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/sessionstore;1"].getService(Ci.nsISessionStore);
```

the tab you are required to provide is not the one from SDK and you need to convert it to XUL tab:

```
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var let lowLevelTab = viewFor(tab);
```

To sum up. If - for example - one would like to add store a value for every added tab it can be done like this:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");

tabs.on('open', tab => {
    var { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');
    var ss = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/sessionstore;1"].getService(Ci.nsISessionStore);
    var lowLevelTab = viewFor(tab);
    ss.setTabValue(lowLevelTab, "key-name-here", "value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to add-on (extension) data persistence that I know of.  One is the [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage), which uses SQLite, and the other is the [simple-storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) which is part of Add-on SDK.  I have found simple-storage to be subject to occasional random bouts of amnesia.

Simple-storage is simply a local file containing a JSON-serializable object.  You initialize it at the beginning of your session as described in the linked documentation, and save it when you want to change values.  It's informationally equivalent to a key-value store, but read and write access involves loading or saving the whole store.

I have found the SQLite interface (Storage) to be reliable, and fast (IF invoked asynchronously).

I do not know whether either or both of these persistence options is slated for future deprecation.  Since they seem to be de-evolving Firefox into Chrome, you might want to try your hand at Chrome extension development, particularly using the [storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), which appears to be a true fully-asynchronous key-value store.